# Mvc bundling based on querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I came across a scenario where the MVC bundling should happen based on the Query string value.

I am using a folder bundling for all *.js inside a folder. My query string will have the sub folder name based on that name i need to bundle only js file inside that folder. So even if we add any folder in run-time and give that in URL the application should be able to load the js file inside the folder. Basically what am looking for to read the query-string in bundle.config and make the folder name of the bundle dynamic

what am looking for is

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/folderbundle")
     .IncludeDirectory("~/JS/"+ [FoldernamefromQueryString] +", "*.js", true)
);
```

Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 1):

After few hours of searching i got something which i was looking for you have to change the code in Global.asax

```
  public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }

        protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var routeData = handler.RequestContext.RouteData;
                var moduleName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ModuleName"]) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ModuleName"] : "Module";
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles, moduleName);
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the bundle.config

```
namespace RouteBundling
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles, string moduleName = "")
        {
            if (moduleName == "Module")
            {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/module").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Module/", "*.js", true));
            }
            else
            {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/module").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Module/" + moduleName + "/", "*.js", true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That pretty much done the job for me. Thank you